# Data to be stored in IMap in hazelcast for caching is stored in hazelcast server or where hazelcast instance is running?

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

I have written hazelcast cache framewrok for caching and dedicated one hazelcast server for caching through constructor injection. Just want to know where is IMap object stored ?Whether it is in my  hazelcast server or  in my application where this class is running?

```
public String hazelClientServer;
public static HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

// setting through constructor injection
public HazelCastCache(String hazelClientServer) {
    this.hazelClientServer = hazelClientServer;
}



private IMap<Object, Object> getMap(String mapName,String configName){

    Config conf = new Config(configName);

    MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig(mapName);
    mapConfig.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU);
    mapConfig.setEvictionPercentage(10);
    conf.addMapConfig(mapConfig);
    conf.getNetworkConfig().setPublicAddress(hazelClientServer);
    hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(conf);
    IMap<Object, Object> hazelMap=hazelcastInstance.getMap(mapName);
    return hazelMap;
}

public Object getDataFromCache(String mapName,String configName,Object key){

    IMap<Object, Object> dataMap = getMap(mapName,configName);
    Object data = dataMap.get(key);
    return data;

}

public void addDataToCache(String mapName,String configName,Object key,Object value){

    IMap<Object, Object> dataMap = getMap(mapName,configName);
    dataMap.put(key, value);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the way you started up the Cluster.

This is what the documentation states:

> In the embedded topology, members include both the data and
>   application. This type of topology is the most useful if your
>   application focuses on high performance computing and many task
>   executions. Since application is close to data, this topology supports
>   data locality.
>
> In the client-server topology, you create a cluster of members and
>   scale the cluster independently. Your applications are hosted on the
>   clients, and the clients communicate with the members in the cluster
>   to reach data.

By looking at your code, you are starting the cluster/node ***in Embedded mode in which case the data resides in your application server itself***. So you need to consider the cache size as well, for allocating the memory for the application container.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion is somewhat useful to me.My thinking was that data resides in hazelcast server, and from there my app is reffering it locally. But when i restart my app. server,cache map is empty somewhat raising ques how data is not persisting since i have  not restarted hazelcast server.Maybe when app server is restarted map in cache server is also reset which can be one possible scenario and second one can be yours.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect on cache reset. In either case, the data resides in Hazelcast container only. But since you started in Embedded mode, if you stop your application server, it will shutdown the Hazelcast cluster also, leading to loss of all data. I would rather suggest you to start the Hazelcast cluster as a standalone and then make use of HazelcastClient to access data from that HZ server.

Comment: Ok..in that case my data will always be there in hazelcast cluster even though i restart my app server unless i do cleanup of cluster??

Comment: Right. It will get evicted based on the eviction policy you have set. I would recommend you to set the maxsize policy as well, based on how often you want the cache to refresh.

Comment: I dont have enough points. So my vote would not be considered.

Comment: I meant to accept the answer. I believe it allows you to accept the answer, as you are the Original poster.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question, but if this code is inside your application it runs inside the application.

Comment: If you have worked in caching,you will understand my qusetion.Cached data is getting stored in IMap above. My question is where is this IMap, in hazelcast server which is outside app or inside my app.

Comment: With an external cluster the data is stored in the cluster (outside your app), in an embedded cluster, the data is stored inside your app (but still in the cluster, since your app itself is the cluster). That said, the data is always stored in the cluster.